# Attempting to add a new column in SQL by subtracting a year

Tags: sql, sql-server

Noob at this. So I will cut to the point on this. This is a class assignment and my professor has not answered emails since Thursday. The problem I am trying to solve is -

"Write a query that will subtract one year from the production date of each album and label this as the RecordDate and display the album title, production date, and record date for each entry in the table.  Order the results by album title."

Here is what the table is supposed to look like[image]

Here is the query I used (given in class I know repeated inserts but what he wanted)...

```
CREATE TABLE ALBUM(
ALBUM_ID char(4) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
ALBUM_TITLE varchar(255),
ALBUM_YEAR year,
ALBUM_PRODUCER varchar(255),

Primary Key(ALBUM_ID)
);

INSERT INTO ALBUM (ALBUM_ID, ALBUM_TITLE, ALBUM_YEAR, ALBUM_PRODUCER)
VALUES ('A001', 'Awake', '1994', 'East West Record');

INSERT INTO ALBUM (ALBUM_ID, ALBUM_TITLE, ALBUM_YEAR, ALBUM_PRODUCER)
VALUES ('A002', 'Moving Pictures', '1981', 'Anthem');

INSERT INTO ALBUM (ALBUM_ID, ALBUM_TITLE, ALBUM_YEAR, ALBUM_PRODUCER)
VALUES ('A003', 'Damage', '2013', 'RCA REcords');

INSERT INTO ALBUM (ALBUM_ID, ALBUM_TITLE, ALBUM_YEAR, ALBUM_PRODUCER)
VALUES ('A004', 'Continuum', '2006', 'Columbia Records');
```

Here is what I used to START to answer the question

```
 ALTER TABLE ALBUM ADD RECORD_DATE INT;
 UPDATE ALBUM SET RECORD_DATE=(ALBUM_YEAR-1);
```

This does make a new column and gives the results for what I want so far (have not gotten to the later part of the question). But this is two different queries...

So, from advice from SQL experts, to achieve what he wants will I have to write multiple queries or can this be done in one single query? Also are my datatypes okay?

**No, I am not asking for the SQL to do this. This isn't a "PLEASE DO MY HOMEWORK FOR ME". And sorry, but it has to all be in cap locks because he wants it that way.**

Comment: I don't think he is looking for an update query or any addition of columns to the base table. Just a `select` query with a calculated column.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it specifically requests that a SQL answer is not desired and it is about interpreting an assignment specification.

Comment: Martin Smith maybe I should have been more specific. Help needed on query - yes if I wasn't doing it correctly. Also, I didn't want someone to do the entire thing for me. I'm trying to learn here and the answers below are of help. I didn't want my entire assignment done.

Comment: Well you ended up with people ignoring your request and the accepted answer pretty much does the whole thing for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andrew the tutor hasn't asked you to add a new column or anything, he has asked you to present data in a specific way.

We store data in SQL Server using some specific rules called [`Database Normalization rules`](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php).

But to show data in any specific form we write `SELECT` queries which select the data from the tables and we use all sorts of functions and methods to manipulate data at run-time and present the data in required structure/format/way.

Similarly in this case for your requirement you do not need to add another column just to do what your tutor as asked to do, it actually violates the rules of normalization. All you need is a simple `SELECT` query, which will show the data in the required format/way.

The select query will be something as simple as ....

```
SELECT [ALBUM_TITLE]     AS [Album Title]
      ,[ALBUM_YEAR]      AS [Production Date]
      ,[ALBUM_YEAR] - 1  AS [Record Date]
FROM ALBUM
ORDER BY [ALBUM_TITLE]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to alter the table at all. You're just going to want to select an additional column. I won't write the full query for you, but I will show you what I mean:

```
SELECT ALBUM_TITLE, ALBUM_YEAR, ALBUM_YEAR - 1 AS  RECORD_DATE
-- rest of the query here --
```